# How to loop through elements in a large list, make NA variables for holes in data, and create new variable in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to avoid writing 78 lines of code by using some sort of loop in R.

Say I have the following:

```
# SST = a large list with 39 elements
# 1 through 39 each represent a single date with sea surface temperature values
# SST[1] = a data.frame with 2630 observations of 9 variables
# SST[[1]] = accesses the data.frame
# SST[1:39] do not have the same number of observations as there are holes in the dataset.
```

I am trying to grab one variable (the mean for each observation) based on the ID variable so I can add this to each day's dataframe.

```
# day1 = data.frame with 9182 observations of 7 variables
# ...
# day39 = data.frame with 9182 observations of 7 variables
```

In order to do this I made a dummy data.frame with 9182 observations to merge to the 39 SST data.frames. I also chose to select only the 2 variables I needed from those (ID and MEAN). I made this a variable, then called this a variable within the data.frame for each day. Doing this manually looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("Id" = c(1:9182))

day1_SST <- merge(df, subset(SST[[1]], select=c(ID, MEAN)), by.x = "Id", by.y = "ID", all.x=TRUE)
day1$SST <- day1_SST$MEAN

day2_SST <- merge(df, subset(SST[[2]], select=c(ID, MEAN)), by.x = "Id", by.y = "ID", all.x=TRUE)
day2$SST <- day2_SST$MEAN
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this in a much less tedious way for all 39 dates.

Comment: Personally, I would flatten the list to a data.frame 1st. `library(plyr);dat <- ldply(SST)` then adding a new variable becomes trivial with something like `ddply(dat, .(.id, ID), transform, mean = mean(something))`.  A reproducible example of what you have and a depiction of what you want would get you an answer quickly.

Comment: As @BrandonBertelsen mentioned a reproducible example would have been easier.  From the last code, I guess you want to subset the 'ID' and 'MEAN' column (which is already created within the `SST` from the description) and `merge` with the 'df' dataset.  Try `lapply(SST, function(x) {x1 <- merge(df, subset(x, select=c('ID', MEAN)), by.x='Id', by.y='ID'); x1$SST <- x1$MEAN})`

Comment: Unfortunately my dataset is so large and complicated that I don't really know how to give any sort of reproducible example. It seems as though it might not be possible to loop through and have all 39 done simultaneously.